# Creating train,test data for Word2Vec model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to create a W2V model and then generate train and test data to be used for my model.My question is how can I generate test data after I am done with creating a W2V model with my train data.

Comment: Can you share more details? The question is very generic. Please share more information like how does your code look or what have you done so far in your code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec is considered an 'unsupervised' algorithm, so at least during its training, it is not typical to hold back any 'test' data for later evaluation.

A Word2Vec model is usually then evaluated on how well it helps some other process - such as the analogy-solving highlighted by the original paper. In gensim, the method `[evaluate_word_analogies()][1]` can repeat that process. But note: word-vectors that perform best on word-analogies my *not* be best for other purposes, like classification or info-retrieval. It's always best to evaluate & tune your word-vectors in a repeatable way that's related to your actual underlying use.

(If you're using the Word2Vec model's outputs - word-vectors specific to your domain – as part of a larger system, where some steps should be evaluated with held-back data, the decision of whether to train the Word2Vec component on all data could go either way, depending on other considerations.)

Comment: so if we have built and trained a word2vec model , how do we test our NN model? Suppose that we have a NN model with an embedding layer ,an LSTM and a Dense layer ..what do we pass as input to the NN model ? I guess an x_train list but how is this list related with the word2vec model ? do we split train and test set from the word2vec model ? how do we preprocess our data based on this word2vec ?

Comment: @XeniaIoannidou Your 5 broad advice questions are too much for a comment on a barely-related answer... and perhaps even overbroad for SO, too – as without a specific focus on a narrow programming task or blocker/challenge, it's a bit like, "How do I build a house from scratch?"

Comment: @dojomo  no it is NOT. i am asking do i need the word2vec only for the embedding layer of my model or should i also preprocess my datasets in a similar way before i pass them to my model???